# Javascript loop returning i and count as undefined

Tags: javascript, for-loop

Could anyone give me insight as to why my variable `message` returns `""` and my variable `i` and `count` return `undefined`?

```
 if (temp.value) {
        temps.push(temp.inputDate, temp.lowTemp, temp.highTemp);
        message = '<h2>Temperature</h2><ol>';
        for (var i = 0, count = temps.length; i < count; i++) {
            message += '<li>' + temps[i] + '</li>'
        }   
        message += '</ol>';
        output.innnerHTML = message;
    }
```

Comment: Can you provide jsfiddle?

Comment: What is the value of `temp`?

Comment: temp is an object I set earlier in the code

Answer (score 0):

Check your for loop conditional, you are not using count anywhere so it is removed.

You have:

```
   for (var i = 0, count = temps.length; i < count; i++) {
            message += '<li>' + temps[i] + '</li>'
        }
```

It should be:

```
   for (var i = 0; i < temps.length; i++) {
     message += '<li>' + temps[i] + '</li>';
   }
```

Comment: Actually he does declare count and uses it in the condition.